# Position a tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have this a href tag that was place inside a p tag. There are 2 a hred inside the p tag. I want to change the position of the other one. Like placing it below the id=nav. I want to do this using jquery because it cant be done manually on wordpress login. I am customizing my wordpress login page.

```
<p id="nav">
        <a href="http://localhost/educontent/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a> |
        <a href="http://localhost/educontent/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" title="Password Lost and Found">Forgot Password</a>
</p>
```

Is it possible to remove the other a href tag  and place it somewhere else via jquery?

Comment: Yeah - pretty broad question though. Do you want to put it in your pocket...?

Comment: Please read the post above carefully thanks. "Like placing it below or somewhere else."

Comment: Define somewhere else. jQuery is sitting there waiting for you to be more specific about where you want to put it.

Comment: Of course that is “possible”. And to find out, _how_ – I’d suggest you start by reading up on the basics of DOM manipulation using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can append it to, before, or after another element.

```
$('#nav a:last').insertAfter('#nav');
```

```
$('#nav a:last').appendTo('#somewhere-else');
```

An `Element` can't have multiple parents, so it will be removed from `<p id="nav">` in the process.